# How to compare and find the differences between two XML files in cocoa?

Tags: objective-c, xml, cocoa, xml-parsing, compare

This is a bit of a two part question, for working with 40mb xml files.

•   What’s a reasonable size to store in memory for a program running continually in the background?
•   How to find what has changed in an XML file.

So on the first read the XML is loaded into NSData, then uploaded to the server.

Now instead of uploading a 40mb XML every time it changes, I would prefer to upload a “delta” file containing only what has changed. The program would monitor the file for change, and activate when it’s been modified.  From what I can see, I would need to parse an old version of the xml file and parse the modified xml file, then compare them? Is it unreasonable to store 80mb in memory like this every time the file is modified?. Now I’m assuming that this has to be done with a DOM parser because I can’t see how you could compare two files like that with a SAX parser since it only has part of the file stored?

I'm a newbie at this so any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NSXMLParser ended up being the most useful for this

Answer (score 0):

To compare two files:

There are many ways to do, (As file is to be considered, I may not be correct):

`sdiff file1.xml file2.xml` A unix command 
You can use this command with apple script.

`-[NSFileManager contentsEqualAtPath:andPath:]` 
This method checks to see if two files at given path are the same file, then compares their size, and finally compares their contents.

For other part:

What size is considered for background process, I dont think so, for an application it matters. You can save these into temporary files. Even safari uses 130+ MB as you can easily check through Activity monitor.

Comment: According to the apple docs, contentsEqualAtPath:andPath: only returns a 'YES' or 'NO', depending if the files are the same. So thats not quite what im looking for, I need to know what parts specifically in the XML have changed.